# Как называется HTML-элемент предназначенный для того чтобы подвешивать к нему скрытые элементы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я давно читал об этом и не могу вспомнить. Фишка была в том что этот элемент содержит другие элементы которые есть на странице, но они пока скрыты. И речь не о `display:none`, и не о `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: Этот элемент - Template

Comment: @Дмытрык Верно! Спасибо! А почему не ответом? Я галочку поставлю.

Comment: не тянет этот ответ на 25 баллов репутации) ... мое личное ощущение)